# How does backpropagation work when some layers are frozen in the network?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gradient-descent

Assume there are two models to be used: X and Y. Data is sequentially passed through X and Y. Only the parameters of model Y need to be optimized with respect to a loss computed over output of model Y. Is the following snippet a correct implementation of this requirement. Few specific queries I need answers to:

1. What does the `with torch.no_grad()` exactly do?
2. As only the parameters of model Y are registered with the optimizer do we still need to freeze model X to be correct or is it only required to reduce the computational load?
3. More generally I want an explanation on how the computation graph and backpropagation behaves in the presence of `with torch.no_grad()` or when some layers are freezed by setting the corresponding `requires_grad` parameter to False.
4. Also comment on whether we can have non-consecutive layers in the network frozen at once.

```
optimizer = AdamW(model_Y.parameters(), lr= , eps= , ...)

optimizer.zero_grad()
with torch.no_grad():
    A = model_X(data)
B = model_Y(A)
loss = some_function(B)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`torch.no_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html#torch.no_grad) serves as a context manager that disables gradient computation. This is very useful for, e.g.,  inference where no use of `.backward()` call will be done. It saves both memory and computations.

In your example, you can treat `A`, the output of `model_X` as your "inputs": you will not modify anything related to `model_X`. In this case, you do not care about gradients w.r.t `model_X`: not w.r.t its parameters nor w.r.t its inputs. It is safe to wrap this call `A = model_X(data)` with the context of `torch.no_grad()`.

However, in other cases, you might not want to modify the weights of `model_X` ("freeze" them), but you might still need to propagate gradients through them - if you want to modify elements feeding `model_X`.
It's all in the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks @Shai for pointing me to the critical difference between the functions of `with torch.no_grad()` and `requires_grad=False`.